# Get key and parent key from a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Below is an array

```html
 [338] => Array
     (
         [0] => Array
             (
                 [ws_id] => Resource id #7                     
             )

         [1] => Array
             (
                 [ws_id] => Resource id #8                    
             )             

     )

 [314] => Array
     (
         [0] => Array
             (
                 [ws_id] => Resource id #10                     
             )

         [1] => Array
             (
                 [ws_id] => Resource id #12                     
             )

     )
```

suppose i have the value "Resource id #8" from which i want to get its key that 1 and parent key ie 338.I already know how to achieve that using foreach loop.I want get a simple way to reduce coding.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a simple nested `foreach` loop.

Comment: I know that very well.But i want know is there any simple  way  to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

A one-dimensional array can be searched with the `array_search()` method. But a multi-dimensional array you have to loop over the first (or n-1) dimension(s) first.

The PHP documentation page of `array_search` [contains a comment](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php#91365) with a method doing so:

```
<?php
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```